# Updating the value of an object inside a loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

I'm currently facing a difficulty in my codes.

First i have an array of objects like this `[{Id:1, Name:"AML", allowedToView:"1,2"}, {Id:2, Name:"Res", allowedToView:"1"}...]` which came from my service

I assign it in variable `$scope.listofResource`

Then inside of one of my objects I have that `allowedToView` key which is a collection of Id's of users that I separate by comma.

Then I have this code...

**Javascript**

```
$scope.listofResource = msg.data
for (var i = 0; i < msg.data.length; i++) {
```

First I run a for loop so I can separate the `Id's` of every user in `allowedToView` key

```
    var allowed = msg.data[i].allowedToView.split(",");
    var x = [];
```

Then I create a variable `x` so I can push a new object to it with a keys of `allowedId` that basically the Id of the users and `resId` which is the Id of the resource

```
    for (var a = 0; a < allowed.length; a++) {
        x.push({ allowedId: allowed[a], resId: msg.data[i].Id });
    }
```

Then I put it in `Promise.all` because I have to get the Name of that "allowed users" base on their Id's using a service

```
    Promise.all(x.map(function (prop) {
        var d = {
            allowedId: parseInt(prop.allowedId)
        }

        return ResourceService.getAllowedUsers(d).then(function (msg1) {
            msg1.data[0].resId = prop.resId;
```

Here it returns the Id and Name of the allowed user. I have to insert the `resId` so it can pass to the return object and it will be displayed in `.then()` below

```
            return msg1.data[0]
        });
    })).then(function (result) {
```

I got the result that I want but here is now my problem

```
        angular.forEach(result, function (val) {
            angular.forEach($scope.listofResource, function (vv) {
                vv.allowedToView1 = [];
                if (val.resId === vv.Id) {
                    vv.allowedToView1.push(val);
```

I want to update `$scope.listofResource.allowedToView1` which should hold an array of objects and it is basically the info of the allowed users. But whenever I push a value here `vv.allowedToView1.push(val);` It always updates the last object of the array.

```
                 }
             })
        })
   });
}
```

So the result of my code is always like this
`[{Id:1, Name:"AML", allowedToView:"1,2", allowedToView:[]}, {Id:2, Name:"Res", allowedToView:"1", allowedToView:[{Id:1, Name:" John Doe"}]}...]`

The first result is always blank. Can anyone help me?

Here is the plunker of it... [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9yAxhBbYlTGRVmyweSm9?p=preview)

Comment: Put the complete code snippet together so that it is readable at a single go as well. Replicating the problem on JSFiddle will make it easier for others to help you sooner

Comment: Its ok now sir. I already put it in plunker

Comment: the problem is in `vv.allowedToView1 = []`, you are overwriting it in a loop every time. You should change the logic so that initialisation of the array will be outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to the solution - [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mos8uAKhBGrUZ75NVjf5?p=preview)

```
for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
  var allowed = msg[i].allowedToView.split(",");
  msg[i].allowedToView1 = [];
  var x = [];
```

Like Aleksey Solovey correctly pointed out, the initialization of the allowedToView1 array is happening at the wrong place. It should be shifted to a place where it is called once for the msg. I've shifted it to after allowedToView.split in the first loop as that seemed a appropriate location to initialize it.

Comment: Oh I totally miss it. Thank you Aleksey Solovey and @Mink. Thank you sirs